# Iterations of while loop returns strange values

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have two questions:

Assume the characters entered by the user in `input` are all contained in `alphabet`:

1. If my `input` starts with `"A"`, the first character in my `output` is `"A"`, but if I start with any other character in `alphabet`, the `output` is the original character shifted to the right by 3. **If my `input` starts with `"A"`, why does my `output` also start at `"A"` and not at `"D"`?**
2. **If my `input` is a string that has spaces (e.g. `"Stack Overflow"`), why is the first word the only component of my `output`? (How is the computer interpreting this?)** I understand C++ considers new lines, spaces, and tabs to be whitespace, but I thought if the space was in a string, it would be treated as a character. **How can I modify my code so the space and the rest of my `input` is included (preferably shifted) in my `output`?**

```
using namespace std;

string alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz @#$%^&*()";   //a 62 character string
string input, output;
int shift = 3, index = 0;

cin >> input;

while(index < input.length()){
   if(alphabet.find(input[index]) != NULL){
       output += alphabet[(alphabet.find(input[index]) + shift) % 62];
   }
   index++;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't `string::find` return `string::npos` if not found? You are comparing to NULL which is different: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/

Comment: @drescherjm yes, it does. Also, the code is calling `alphabet.find(input[index])` twice, it should call it once and cache the result to a variable, and then use that where needed: `string::size_type found_index = alphabet.find(input[index]); if (found_index != string::npos) { output += alphabet[(found_index + shift) % 62]; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If my input starts with `"A"`, the first character in my `output` is `"A"`, but if I start with any other character in alphabet, the `output` is the original character shifted to the right by 3. **If my `input` starts with `"A"`, why does my `output` also start at "A" and not at `"D"`?**

It doesn't.  It skips the `"A"` and does not add it to the `output` at all!

This is because `std::string::find()` DOES NOT return a pointer, it returns an index.  If it does not find a match, it returns `std::string::npos` (-1).  Comparing `NULL` to an index treats the `NULL` as index 0.  So, when `find()` does find `"A"`, it returns 0, which you then compare as equal to `NULL` (0) and thus *skip* adding `"D"` to the `output`.  All of the other `input` characters make `find()` return indexes other than 0, so they don't compare equal to `NULL` and so you shift all of them (including ones that cause `find()` to return `npos`, you shift all of those to index 2).

> **If my `input` is a string that has spaces (e.g. `"Stack Overflow"`), why is the first word the only component of my `output`? (How is the computer interpreting this?)** I understand C++ considers new lines, spaces, and tabs to be whitespace, but I thought if the space was in a string, it would be treated as a character. **How can I modify my code so the space and the rest of my `input` is included (preferably shifted) in my `output`?**

`operator>>` reads whitespace-delimited words.  It first skips leading whitespace (unless `std::noskipws` is used), and then it reads until it encounters whitespace.  To read a string with spaces in it, use `std::getline()` instead.

With that said, try this instead:

```
using namespace std;

const string alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz @#$%^&*()";   //a 62 character string
string input, output;
const int shift = 3;

getline(cin, input);

for (string::size_type index = 0; index < input.length(); ++index) {
   string::size_type found_index = alphabet.find(input[index]);
   if (found_index != string::npos) {
       output += alphabet[(found_index + shift) % alphabet.size()];
   }
}

/*
Or, using C++11 or later:

for (char c : input) {
   auto found_index = alphabet.find(c);
   ... (same as above) ...
}

*/
```

> Also, how does one format variables when asking questions on StackOverflow so that they're in little code blocks within writing a question? I see that on other people's posts, but I don't know how to do it, and it makes things far more readable.

Blocks of code can be indented by 4 spaces.  The toolbar on StackOverflow's editor has a button for formatting code blocks.  Just select the code and press the button.

Code inline of other text can be wrapped in `` quotes.

Click on the `?` button on the right side of the editor's toolbar to see the supported formatting markup.